# True or false? Prove it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Is this true or false?

I've tried proven that if $B=0$, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$, but I don't know how to do it when $\operatorname{rank}(B)$ isn't zero.

Comment: Do you know that rank($AB$)$\le$ rank ($B$) whatever properties $A$ has (think of the dimension of the image, which cannot increase)? Apply twice using $A^{-1}$ appropriately.

Comment: your question title is not descriptive at all.

Answer (score 3):

You surely know that, in general,
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(B)
$$

By the same reason,
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A^{-1}AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(AB)
$$

---

How to see $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(B)$? This requires the rank-nullity theorem (but there are other proofs). Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times p$. Then we can define linear maps
\begin{align}
f_A&\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m, && f_A(v)=Av\\
f_B&\colon\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^n, && f_B(w)=Bw\\
f_{AB}&\colon\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^n && f_{AB}(w)=ABw
\end{align}
It is obvious that $f_{AB}=f_A\circ f_B$ and that $\ker f_{B}\subseteq\ker f_{AB}$. By the rank-nullity theorem
\begin{align}
p&=\dim\ker f_B+\operatorname{rank}(B)\\
&=\dim\ker f_{AB}+\operatorname{rank}(AB)
\end{align}
and, since $\dim\ker f_B\le\dim\ker f_{AB}$, we deduce that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(B)
$$

Comment: However in my question, if rank(AB) < rank(B) it's proven to be wrong. Is there any examples I can use to prove it's false in that case?

Comment: @Trent Sorry, but I don't understand: if $A$ is invertible, then the ranks of $AB$ and $B$ are equal, so it can't happen that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)<\operatorname{rank}(B)$. This may happen if $A$ is *not* invertible; for example, take $A=0$ and $B\ne0$.

Comment: @Trent Note that this answer mirrors my comment - you have rank$(B)=$rank$(A^{-1}AB)\le $rank$ (AB)\le $rank$ (B)$ so the inequalities in the middle must be be equalities.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
The statement is true, because $\mathrm{rank}(A) = n$, i.e. all columns of $A$ are linearly independent (*wich implies...*)

Comment: How can I use that to show rank(AB) = n? I'm just a little lost I can't even think

Comment: Look at what $A$ does to the image of $B$. Can it reduce its dimension?

Comment: I can visualize it perfectly. My thoughts are that multiplying matrix A by matrix B won't change the dimension at all (in respect to the dimension of B). I understand this, but I'm not sure how to show it on paper.

Comment: Start with let $x,y$ with $Bx \ne By$, then $ABx \ne ABy$ because ..., so $\dim(\mathrm{range}(B)) = \dim(\mathrm{range}(AB))$.

Comment: okay I think I got it! Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

True. Because the dimension of the kernal of $AB$ is the same as the dim of the kernel of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the columns of $B$ to form a spanning set for a subspace. Suppose you know the dimension of that subspace and it is $d$. Now, for the columns of $AB$, can you find linear combinations that span that subspace also giving dimension $d$? And if so, is it ever possible that rank$(AB)$ > rank$(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

rank(AB)≤ min{rank(A), rank(B)} implies rank(AB) ≤ rank(B)

Given  A is invertible.

rank(B)=rank(A−1AB)≤ min{rank(A−1), rank(AB)},A−1 means the inverse of A. i.e, rank(B)≤rank(AB)

Thus, rank (AB)=rank(B).